# Why a revert a file in EGit, but the dirty symbol '<' still exist in the project view?

Tags: revert, egit

I try EGit revert for several days, It's very confuse that when I revert the file following the user guide, and I still got the file dirty symbol in the related file.

http://wiki.eclipse.org/EGit/User_Guide#Reverting_Changes

I choose 'Replace with' -> 'File in Git Index', it works, the content has been revert, but the symbol stays the same, sometimes, the symbol will disappear after a while, but sometimes, it didn't disappear.

I'm using eclipse on windows, I'm not sure it's about the '\r\n' character. But I use 'Compare with ' -> 'File in Git Index', two files look the same.

Hope someone can tell me why, I think it can be a bug? Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are trying to revert the file back to the version in the latest commit you should use the Replace with > HEAD Revision action.

Running this action should remove the dirty symbol from the file's decorations.

Comment: Yes, because I don't understand the index and head diff at the beginning, thanks.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem, just today. And I was doing "Revert to HEAD" revision and still the "dirty" symbol ">" would still be there.

First only restart Eclipse have helped, but after I tried to press "refresh" button in the "Git Staging" view. And this has removed the file from the staging view from "Unstaged changes" list and also removed the "dirty >" mark.

Hope this helps.

I used  Eclipse
Version: 4.2.1.v20130118-173121-9MF7GHYdG0B5kx4E_SkfZV-1mNjVATf67ZAb7
Build id: M20130204-1200

with android development tools ADT
Build: v22.0.1-685705

under Windows 8 64